# Google Play Location services api fallback

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I want to implement the new Google Play location services api in my app, but my app must run on older phones as well, even the ones with limited space and without the play services installed. How can I set up a fallback if the GPLS is not installed? I tried moving the location listener over to another class, but that wouldn't work. I hope some of you can help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a support library that supports backward compatibility. And if that fails, you can always fall back on the framework APIs. In your case, that would be [Location APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

HTH